# See the contents of OpenAI Fine Tuned Model Results in Python using the OpenAI API

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api

I have fine tuned a GPT-3 model for classification. The model status still shows `pending`. However, the model events show that `"Fine-tune succeeded.` I even get an event showing the uploaded file id. When I download the results file using the following code and print its content, I see the following result:

```
content = openai.File.download("file-coumSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
contents = content.decode()


# Print the contents of the file
print(content)
```

**Results:**

```
b'{\n  "object": "file",\n  "id": "file-coumSxMyXfxQhXEVYLNMWL5F",\n  "purpose": "fine-tune-results",\n  "filename": "compiled_results.csv",\n  "bytes": 168364,\n  "created_at": 1673135506,\n  "status": "processed",\n  "status_details": null\n}\n'
```

Can somebody recommend how I can see the contents of the `compiled_results.csv` file?